# Big user activity sequences to a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, custom-controls, data-mining, bigdata

Maybe this is not a perfect place to ask question like this.

The scenario is that I have a big log file about 10,000,000 lines in it.
Each line represents an activity of a user.
There are about 20 kinds of activities.

I want to use this data to generate a tree, which edge represents a kind of activity(and weight), and node represent a state.

For example, say that I have log like this:
(suggest that date is well sorted)

```
user_id| activity
u1     | a1
u1     | a2
u2     | a1
u3     | a2
u3     | a3
u4     | a1
u4     | a2
u4     | a3
```

Then I hope to get some thing like this:

[image: output tree]

I tried to save each state-forward, and how many times a state-forward is performed like below.

```
current_state | verb | next_state | weight
0             | a1   | 1          | 3
1             | a2   | 2          | 2
0             | a2   | 3          | 1
3             | a3   | 4          | 1
2             | a3   | 5          | 1
```

But the states are just too many, even if I use a cache mechanism to save all the frequent state-forwards in a hash and only when a state-forward queued out of that hash I would persist, it still load too slowly.

So maybe I need an algorithm would prune during the tree construction.

Do you know any thing to work this out?
Any tool or package is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to do this.

First, I assume that you're keeping a list (perhaps a dictionary) of users and their current states. So that when you see a log entry for user 2 and verb a3, you can look user 2 up in your dictionary, see that he's currently at state 3, and push him to state 4 (or whatever).

It's those state transitions that you're trying to count.

The easiest way to do it is for every log entry you read, write an entry to a file (or save it in a list). The entry has `(current_state, verb, next_state)`. After you've gone through all of the log entries, you load that file, sort it by `current_state` and `next_state`. What you'll have is:

```
state1,state2
state1,state2
...
state1,state3
state1,state3
...
```

You can go through and count the duplicate lines, which will tell you how many of each state transition was made.

I can't imagine that going through 10 million lines would take very long. If I assume your lines are 160 characters long that's still less than 2 gigabytes. So you should be able to read the file in under a minute, and processing can't take very long.

The other way to do it involves keeping a dictionary that's indexed by `(current_state,next_state)`, and updating it as you read each record. It would be faster than the map/reduce technique I described, but it will require more memory.